# Solución a error: Got packets out of order

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con un equipo remoto que se conecta a una base de datos, pero después de un tiempo de estar funcionando me sale el siguiente error:

```
1156 : Got packets out of order.
```

Agradezco me puedan decir como se resuelve este problema o que significa.

Answer (score 0):

A mí me pasó que fallaba desde el inicio, y era porque puse el mismo puerto para la base que para el servicio web que consumía la base. Cambié el puerto de la base tanto en la config del server como en mi código fuente, y comenzó a funcionar a la perfección.